# macro that includes align* environment doesn't use predefined macro

Tags: macros, align

What could there be some reasons of because the `align*` environment doesn't use the `Finished` predefined macro?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% ============ Itemize ============
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Itemize}[2]
{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item #1
        \item #2
    \ItemizeFinished
}
\newcommand{\ItemizeFinished}{\end{itemize}}

% ============ Align ============
\newcommand{\Align}[2]
{
    \begin{align*}
        #1 &= #2
    \AlignFinished
}
\newcommand{\AlignFinished}{\end{align*}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \Align{1}{2}
\end{document}
```

Isn't it supposed that the `\AlignFinished` is called when the `\Align` command reaches its end?

I get the following error on `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)`

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{align*} on input line 27 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.28 \end{document}

?
```

Comment: `align` grabs the contents of the environment until it finds the `\end{align}`, and it doesn't expands tokens when doing so. This means that `\AlignFinished` "hides" the `\end{align}`. Why do you need to put the `\end` part in a macro?

Comment: Why does the `align` environment doeesn't work as the `itemize` environment does? The `itemize` accepts the command I've written.

The reason I want to put the `\end{align}` on a different macro is because I'm want to create a `\Align` that accepts a variable number of parameters, just as I did with `Itemize` (see https://pastebin.com/iGnRg21z)

Comment: Because the implementation of `align` is different. Once an `itemize` starts it will execute everything until finding an `\end{itemize}`. The `align` environment searches for and explicit `\end{align}`, more or less in the same fashion as a command looks for something between `{` and `}`. To implement the command you want you need to first grab everything and only then start the `align` environment. How would you know if `\Align{1}{2}{3}{4}` is one row with four columns or two rows with two columns?

Comment: the amsmath documentation does document that you can not do this

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If what you say is true, then I have no more doubts.

As a C++ user, I though that the LaTeX compiler first used a preprocessor. That is, it first replaces all user-macros with their meaning and then the compiler compiles the entire source code, without having to analize user macros, because they were already replaced by the preprocessor, but it seems that LaTeX doesn't work like that.

Comment: Tex is a macro expansion language there is no compiler in that sense it never holds the document in memory it just expands as far as it needs to evaluate the next command